# Multiplying oscillator signal with a pulse

Tags: oscillator, multiplier, differential-amplifier

I am trying to multiply my oscillator sine signal with my pulse. But, the voltage of the oscillator is too big so it saturates.
[image]

This is the output I am getting from my oscillator. I am getting the required 100kHz frequency for my oscillator by would like to reduce the voltage in order to feed it into my diff amp. 
[image]

If I just add an 10mV sine input instead of the 300mV that I am getting from the oscillator, the circuit works properly. Can I reduce the voltage in the oscillator so that the output doesn't saturate or is there any way to change my diff amp in order for the output signal to not saturate.

My output when the signal from the oscillator is 300mV
[image]

My output when I feed a very small input sine wave into the input of the diff amp and my required output
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your last picture isn't multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put 1k resistors in series with each of the emitters of Q1 and Q2 to reduce the gain of the differential amp. This is called emitter degeneration.

Answer (score 0):

Title: -

> *Multiplying oscillator signal with a pulse*

Your thinking seems muddled. Because: -

> *My output when I feed a very small input sine wave into the input of
>   the diff amp and my required output*

The so-called *required output* is not multiplication - it is generally a straightforward addition. But, it's unclear why you want to add two signals (as per the 2nd circuit) when your title is about multiplying. Your top circuit multiplies but your bottom circuit just adds. Be clear and explain what you are ultimately wanting.

If you want multiplication then **use the differential output from the two collectors in the top circuit** - that gives you amplitude modulation aka multiplication. In case your unsure about what I'm saying: -

[image]